# Why I am unable to assert that an email has been sent from a laravel job?

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.7

In laravel I need tot est the following job:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\AnotharJob;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class AJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
      //Some logic here

      AnotharJob::dispatch();
    }
}
```

In laravel I need tot est the following job:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Mail\MyMail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class AnotharJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
      $myMail= new MyMail();
      Mail::to('user@example.com')->send($myMail)
    }
}
```

And in order to test the `AJob` job I wrote the following test:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use App\Jobs\AJob;
use App\Mail\MyMail;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class AJobTest extends BaseTestCase
{

    private $jobPid;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        // Setup Queue Listener
        exec('php artisan queue:listen --env=testing > /tmp/output.txt 2>&1 & echo $!', $pid);
        $this->jobPid=(int)$pid[0];
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        // ShutDown Queue Listener
        exec("kill -9 {$this->jobPid}");
    }

   public function testJobSendsEmail()
   {
      Mail::fake();
      AJob::dispatchNow();
      sleep(5);
      
      Mail::assertSent(MyMail::class, function($mail){
         return $mail->subject == "Hello";
      });

   }
}
```

But once I run the test I get the following error:

```
1) Tests\Jobs\AJobTest::testJobSendsEmail
The expected [App\Mail\MyMail] mailable was not sent.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Testing/Fakes/MailFake.php:48
/var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:237
/var/www/html/api/tests/Jobs/AJobTest.php:34
```

So do you know why I am unable to assert that an email was not sent?

My whole testing idea is to run the jobs in a testing environment and then assert any mail sent or database changes, in other words to perform an integration test.

Comment: You can assert that events were dispatched, and that emails were sent, without needing to run the queue worker like that. Is there a reason you're doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a real good reason to have a queue listener for your tests it is probably easier to run all of your queue items synchronously. This is primarily why the "sync" option for queue drivers exists, so that you ensure that they run in sync with the rest of your code and therefore you can test it. The "sync" queue connection will execute any Job or Event that normally would go into a queue but instead execute synchronously. So, for example, if you have a job that implements ShouldQueue but your QUEUE_CONNECTION is set to "sync" then all of the code in the Job will be executed when you dispatch the Job immediately before going onto the next line of code. So, In your .env file set

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

Then `php artisan config:clear` and that should fix it.